# assign the READ privilege to userGroup1 of 4 tables in a DolphinDB database

Tags: dolphindb

I have many databases created. I want to assign to userGroup1 the READ privilege to 4 tables out of the total of 6 tables in the database db1. How can I use `grant` to specify the usergroup and tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the official docs: https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/CommandsReferences/g/grant.html on function `grant`.
Sample code for your reference:

```
grant(`group1, TABLE_READ, "dfs://db1/table1")
grant(`group1, TABLE_READ, "dfs://db1/table2")
grant(`group1, TABLE_READ, "dfs://db1/table3")
grant(`group1, TABLE_READ, "dfs://db1/table4")
```